# a vector equation for the line $y=3x$ and the line $x+y=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In two dimensions find, using column vectors, a vector equation for the line $y=3x$ and the line $x+y=1$.

How to find?

Comment: Let $x=t,\ t\in\Bbb R$.  Then $\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{t \\ 3t},\ t\in\Bbb R$.  Easy, see?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one  $$ \begin{bmatrix}
 y  & x  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\ -3  \end{bmatrix}=0$$
The second can be done in the same way.

Comment: Only one of those is a column matrix.  I'm pretty sure they want the answer I give in the comments (you can go ahead and take it if you want ).

Comment: Can't we suppose that the first is the transpose of a column vector  ?

Comment: Of course.  I just think that's not what OP's professor is looking for (but maybe it is).

Comment: @Bye_World don't worry, hope fully  the OP will find his answer, and we can learn , no matter who write the right answer  :)